# Close Oracle database connection

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I am new to unix shell scripting and need a suggestion.

I have shell script which connects to the oracle db fetch the value and assign it outpt variable as mentioned below.

```
outpt=$(sqlplus Username/Pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=10.255.244.15)(Port=1674))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=abc01))) <<EOF
set pages 0 echo off feed off
select max(date_sent) from test;
exit;
EOF
)
```

In windows we close the connection explicitly after executing the query. Is the code above implicitly do that for me or i have to explictly close connection.
If yes . Please help.

Comment: I think the `exit` statement in your script should close your Oracle connection for  you.

Comment: `exit` closes the connection.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my understanding.